# Encountered "executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache python g++ make]: exit code: 21" while building docker image

Tags: docker

I was following [this](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/) guide for building a simple docker image, but encountered error:
`executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache python g++ make]: exit code: 21`
Following is the Dockerfile I'm using:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM node:12-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache python g++ make
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN yarn install --production
CMD ["node", "src/index.js"]
```

Please suggest me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

replace python with python2

```
RUN apk add --no-cache python2 g++ make
```

Phyton is now missing from source and was replaced by  python2